# Does Lipschitz continuity on $[a,b]$ and differentiability on $(a,b)$ imply differentiability at $b$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is Lipschitz continuous. Suppose also that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that there is a continuous function $g: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ which has the property that $g(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Is it necessarily the case that $f$ is differentiable at $b$ (in the sense of left-side limits) and, moreover that the derivative of $f$ at $b$ is $g(b)$.

Comment: Since the function isn't defined on the right side of $b$, i.e., $(b,\infty)$, I think it doesn't make sense to ask about right hand differentiability (or even continuity) at $b$.

Comment: Sorry, left-side. Corrected.

Comment: We are given $f'(x)$ exists for $x\in (0,b).$ What sense does it make to say $f'$ is continuous on $[0,b]?$

Comment: @zhw. I guess what I mean to say is that there is a function called $f'$ that is continuous on $[0,b]$ with the property that $f'(x)$ is equal to the derivative of $f$ at $x$ for all $x \in (0,b)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you just want to say $f',$ which is defined on $(0,b),$ has a continuous extension to $[0,b].$ You should make that clear in the question. I'm not sure why you include $0$ in this.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the feedback. I've made the question clearer and switched it to $(a,b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need all of those assumptions. Assume $n=1.$ Suppose $f:(a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b),$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-} f'(x)$ exists. Then $f'(b)$ exists (as a left sided derivative).

Proof: Choose any $c\in (a,b).$ Then $f$ is continuous on $[c,b]$ and differentiable in $(c,b).$ For any $x\in (c,b),$ the mean value theorem shows there exists $c_x\in (x,b)$ such that

$$\tag 1 \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x} = f'(c_x)$$

As $x\to b^-,$ $c_x\to b^-.$ By our assumption on $f,$ $\lim_{x\to b^-} f'(c_x)$ exists. Thus by $(1),$ $f'(b)$ exists.

So we're done for $n=1,$ and the result for higher dimensions follows easily.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the Lipschitz-constant, i.e. $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L |x-y|$. Then $|f'(x)| \leq L$ for all $x \in (0,b)$. Thus, the derivative is bounded. However, $f$ do not have to be differentiable in $0$ or $b$.

Counterexample: Let $\rm{Si}(x) := \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, \rm{d}t$, then $f(x) = \rm{Si}(1/x) +x \cos(1/x)$ has the derivate $f'(x)=\sin(1/x)$. Since $f'$ is bounded, $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous on $[0,1]$. (Note that we can define $f$ also in $x=0$.) However, $f$ is not differentiable in $0$.

Comment: I notice in your counterexample that the derivative is not continuous at $x=0$. I guess maybe I should've been clearer as to where $f'$ is continuous

Comment: Oh, I overlooked this while reading. If $f'$ can be extened contiuoulsy in $0$ and $b$ the statement is true. (This fact is also often stated in books on books on analysis.)